# Angular - Add debounce to an event

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using mouseenter and mouseleave events to handle sidenav opening and closing in my app.
I would like to add a bit of debounce  to these events, because right now if you hover the container with these events fast, these events are being called a lot of times and I'm getting weird behavior with my sidenav. How can I add debounce to these events ? Is it event possible ?

Comment: what you tried so far so we can find out what went wrong

Comment: If you are using the `fromEvent` rxjs method you could add a `debounce` to the pipe to modify your observable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a template reference variable on your button :

```
<button #button>Click me</button>
```

Reference it inside your component using *@ViewChild*

```
@ViewChild('button') button: ElementRef;
```

Use *fromEvent* from rxjs to listen to the *click* event and use the *debounceTime* operator :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
      debounceTime(2000) // 2 seconds
    ).subscribe(() => {
      // do whatever
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

RXJS has a function **[FromEvent](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEvent)** which convert event to Stream
u have to create two streams ,one on enter and other on leave

I think with **[debounceTime](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime)** u should use **[distinctUntilChanged](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged)** as well.
otherwise it will emit true true, or false false , but u need true false or false true sequence

```
 @ViewChild('sizeMenu')
  set SizeMenu(sizeMenu: ElementRef) {
    let mouseEnter$ = fromEvent(sizeMenu.nativeElement, 'mouseenter').pipe(
     mapTo(true));

     let mouseLeave$ = fromEvent(sizeMenu.nativeElement, 'mouseleave').pipe(
     mapTo(false));


     this.mouseEvents$ = mouseLeave$.pipe(merge(mouseEnter$), debounceTime(this.DebounceTime), distinctUntilChanged());
  };
```

this is [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stream-from-mouse-enter-angular?file=src/app/app.component.tsfile=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) on stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directive which you can add to your input then. In this example I debounce click event, but you can easily accomodate it to any other event.

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
    selector: '[debounceClick]'
})

export class DebounceClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @Input()
    public debounceClickTime = 500;

    @Output()
    public debounceClick = new EventEmitter();

    private clicks = new Subject();
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor() { }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.clicks.pipe(debounceTime(this.debounceClickTime)).subscribe((e: Event) =>
            this.debounceClick.emit(e));
    }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    public clickEvent(event: Event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        this.clicks.next(event);
    }

}
```

And use it in your HTML in a following way:

```
<input type="text" (debounceClick)="yourMethod()" debounceClickTime="1000" />
```

`debounceClickTime` is optional and if you do not use it, it debounces by default in 500ms.